# my post method returns (u'') and django saves includes the (u'') string when saving it

Tags: python, django, post

This is how I retrieve the post data from the webpage. The person models can be saved but it includes the `"(u'')"` string. For example if change the `firstname` to "Alex", it gets the raw value `u('Alex')` and saves it.

```
def submit_e(req, person_id=None):

if(req.POST):

    try:
        person_id = req.POST['driver']
        person = Person.objects.get(pk=person_id)


        person.firstname = req.POST['firstname'],
        person.midname   = req.POST['middleinitial'],
        person.lastname  = req.POST['lastname'],

        person.full_clean()
        person.save()
    except Exception as e:
        print e
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('users:user_main'))
```

Comment: Why aren't you using a `Form`?

Comment: Or more specifically, a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/). This is what they are designed for.

Comment: Hi, I did not bother to use the Form of Django since the templates were already made.

Comment: So what. That's only half of what a `Form` does.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly how the quotation marks and parentheses you're seeing in your data are arranged? Is the `u` before the parentheses (like a function call `u("foo")` or inside them (marking a unicode literal `(u"foo")`). If the latter, is there a comma at the end of the parentheses (e.g. `(u"foo",)`? That would mean you're getting a 1-tuple, rather than a plain value.

Comment: Thank you, I think need try the Form first. This is actually the first time that I experienced a problem using the regular form and I already finish two modules so I thought I can carry on without the Django's Form or ModelForm.

Comment: (u'Christian',), this is what I get for every field in my form and django saves it directly.

Answer (score 0):

*NB: the following is my best guess at what you are seeing based on your question. If I have guessed wrongly, the please update your post with more details - putting `print` statements throughout your code and adding the output to your post would be a good start.*

The `u` prefix on a string indicates a Unicode string. It is not actually part of the contents of the string. If we create a string in the interpreter:

```
>>> name = u'Me'
```

and then request details of the string,

```
>>> name
u'Me'
```

then the `u` is shown as it is part of the information about the string, which is what we have requested. If we print the contents of the string

```
>>> print name
Me
```

then the `u` is not shown (just like the quotes aren't shown).

Using the interpreter to try and reproduce your problem, I created a new user with a Unicode string for a username:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> new_user = User()
>>> new_user.username = u'Me'
>>> new_user.save()
```

And as before, if we request the details about the string we see the `u` and the quotes, but if we print the contents of the string we don't:

```
>>> new_user.username
u'Me'
>>> print new_user.username
>>> Me
```

To further confirm the `u` was not stored, we can explore the database directly:

```
sqlite> select username from auth_user;
Me
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I think I know where to start debugging the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need to delete the "," at the end of each line
so, before:

```
person.firstname = req.POST['firstname'],
person.midname   = req.POST['middleinitial'],
person.lastname  = req.POST['lastname'],
```

after

```
person.firstname = req.POST['firstname']
person.midname   = req.POST['middleinitial']
person.lastname  = req.POST['lastname']
```